# Do something before app removing

Tags: java, android

I've got an app that stores few files on sd card. I want my app to remove those files, if user wants to delete the application. How can I do that? Is there a method like `onDelete()` or something?

Comment: Unfortunately the ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED intent will be sent out to all receivers except for your own.

Comment: ... provide an online backup facility?

Answer (score 3):

> I've got an app that stores few files on sd card. I want my app to
>   remove those files,

Don't store them directly on the `sdcard`. Use the app's cache space or the directory pointed by [getExternalFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)). Both are cleaned up by the system when the app is uninstalled

Answer (score 2):

**No**, there is no way for you app to know when it is being deleted/removed from a device.

> Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED
>
> Broadcast Action: An existing application package has been removed from the device.
>   The data contains the name of the package. **The package that is being installed does not receive this Intent.**

This comes mostly because if a code would be executed on the app that was about to be removed some might prevent removal etc.

You should provide an option to your users to wipe sdcard data, or use another storage option (that is linked to your app), but I guess you're using the sdcard on purpose.